# Is it unethical in the Buddhist view to attend work ill?

Tags: karma, sila, right-intention, right-action

You know, and increase risk of others getting the illness and such?

Comment: Why would one want to attend work when one is ill? Not only do you increase the risk of possibly making others unwell but also not providing the opportunity for yourself to recover. The sooner you recover, the better you are in fulfilling what you do for work.

Comment: @Motivated I don't know why, but people do all the time.

Comment: I am aware that people do it all the time and from the conversations i have had it occurs for various reasons. These include demands and expectations of work e.g. we need that report today, the workloads on staff especially when various roles are being fulfilled by one person, policies on sick leave, etc. Most of the time, people who are unwell don't want to be focusing on work but "feel" they need to e.g. how will i be perceived, what if someone else does a better job than me, what if they find out that i am not doing as well as i should be, etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't square well against the notion of Right Action (or Right Conduct) on the Noble Eightfold Path.

> The practitioner should train oneself to be morally upright in one's activities, not acting in ways that would be corrupt ***or bring harm to oneself or to others***. ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noble_Eightfold_Path#Right_action)) (emphasis added)

If going to work while ill could cause others to become ill, that would be bringing harm to others. So it's probably not a good idea.